# Removing particular string in python pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I have a data frame with a column gender. It consists of predictions of the gender. Now the gender column has values such as mostly_male, mostly_female. I want to remove mostly. So I tried`df['gender'] = df['gender'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('mostly_'))`

But I got a column with values of 'male' corresponding to 'ale'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use replace:

```
 df['gender'] = df['gender'].str.replace('mostly_', '')
```

This will replace any exact matches of "mostly_" with a blank "". Your example will remove leading characters from a line if any of them are found in the string you pass it. So "m" is found by lstrip, and "mostly_" is removed but since there is an "m" in "male", it will be removed as well.

Comment: Great answer! It may also be helpful to inform the OP why the `m` in `male` was removed as well. `lstrip()` takes as an input the set of characters to be removed, and seeing as `m` is one of those characters, it will also remove the `m` in `male`: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lstrip.html

Answer (score 6):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.replace`

You can pass a dictionary to this method to specify which column to work with

```
df.replace({'gender': {'mostly_': ''}}, regex=True)
```

---

#### `pandas.Series.str.replace`

Advantage is that you don't need to specify `regex=True`

```
df.gender.str.replace('mostly_', '')
```

---

#### `pandas.Series.str`

Voted "Mostly_likely" to break.  But if you know that all entries start with `"mostly_"` then why not

```
df.gender.str[7:]
```

---

#### `pandas.Series.map`

I don't like the other options because they all involve string manipulations.  You can be more explicit with a dictionary mapping and keep to constant time lookups

```
df.gender.map({'mostly_male': 'male', 'mostly_female': 'female'})
```

---

### Timing

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(gender=[f"mostly_{g}" for g in ['male', 'female'] * 10000]))
```

#### Test

```
%timeit df.replace({'gender': {'mostly_': ''}}, regex=True)
%timeit df.gender.str.replace('mostly_', '')
%timeit df.gender.str[7:]
%timeit df.gender.map({'mostly_male': 'male', 'mostly_female': 'female'})

100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.42 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Vote for speed  :-)

Comment: Thank you @Wen (-:

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` to remove unwanted string. `lstrip` will remove all the characters matching the criteria. For details [lstrip docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lstrip.html)
Also can use regex library to substitute a substring

```
import re
df['gender'].map(lambda x: re.sub('^mostly_','',x))
```